# Splitting a Python list based on criteria

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a python list as follows:

```
mylist = [('Item A','CA','10'),('Item B','CT','12'),('Item C','CA','14')]
```

I would like to split it into a list based on column 2 == 'CA'

Desired Output:

```
filtered_list = [('Item A','CA','10'),('Item C','CA','14')]
```

My Attempt: Clearly there are some issues here!

```
mylist = [('Item A','CA','10'),('Item B','CT','12'),('Item C','CA','14')]
filtered_list[]
for row in mylist:
    if [row:1] = 'CA'
       filtered_list.append(mylist[row])
```

Comment: Yes there are some issues. First you are using a tuple as a slice value and then you are not using the comparison operator `==` and again you are using a tuple as an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to achieve this:

```
mylist = [('Item A','CA','10'),('Item B','CT','12'),('Item C','CA','14')]

filtered_list = [item for item in mylist if item[1]=='CA']
```

Comment: Is it possible to not include a value in the new list if a a certain criteria if a similar entry already exists? For example, I only want one entry of Item A where column 3 is 14.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's filter for this purpose in the following way.

```
filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] =='CA',mylist)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing my own answer I would like to point out where you went wrong with an explanation.

```
mylist = [('Item A','CA','10'),('Item B','CT','12'),('Item C','CA','14')]
filtered_list[]                         ## I believe this was typo 
for row in mylist:
    if [row:1] = 'CA'                    ## this where you missed it!
       filtered_list.append(mylist[row])
```

I have corrected your code.

```
mylist = [('Item A','CA','10'),('Item B','CT','12'),('Item C','CA','14')]
filtered_list = []                        ## list created
for row in mylist:
    if row[1] == 'CA':                    ## == for if condition and : 
        filtered_list.append(row)         ## appending the row if row[1] == "CA"
print filtered_list
```

Comment: Seeing it with my own code was super useful, thanks! Is this an inefficient way of doing things?

Comment: No.Not unless you are worried about memory and execution time. The answers provided by others here are concise way of writing the same functionality. I think you should use your own code because it'll be easy for you to debug it. If you plan on using any other code then make you sure you understand how it is being done and then go ahead :)